# Command 'free': what does the "Shared" field indicates?

Tags: linux

I want to know what "Shared" Column indicates in the `free` command.

```
                 total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3818       3677        140         37         92        769
-/+ buffers/cache:       2815       1002
Swap:         3956          0       3956
```

Comment: On my Slackware box `man free` says that `The shared memory column should be ignored; it is obsolete.`